# Neo4j 3.1 browser errors on large/long running query

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, neo4j

I'm working on a moderately large query

```
MATCH path = ((s:User {UserId:"indexedKey"})-[r:HasAccess]-(t:User)) WHERE all(y IN rels(path) WHERE toInt(y.Importance) >= 3) RETURN path
```

Expected result ~3,000 nodes; unknown edges, probably >6,000. The browser errors out before returning results. When I limit the range (i.e.)

```
MATCH path = ((s:User {UserId:"indexedKey"})-[r:HasAccess*3]-(t:User)) WHERE all(y IN rels(path) WHERE toInt(y.Importance) >= 3) RETURN path*
```

it returns without issue.

Server: Neo4j 3.1.1 CE on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS under Hyper-V on Windows 10. VM with 4 virtual cores, unlimited claim on Host; Assigned 7GB out of 11GB Max in VM. Neo4j Heap = 5G, and pagecache.size = 5G.

Client: Windows 10 with Chrome 64-bit and Firefox 64-bit, same behavior. Different host from the server.

The failure occurs after an indeterminate time (left to run overnight) i get [Error from Chrome 64-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWbXP.png). Watching the resources on the client side i see ~300 MB/s coming into the the browser, browser memory steadily increases. I've seen it hit 6 GB (Firefox 64-Bit). After a recent update Chrome 64-bit increases it's memory usage at a significantly slower rate.

Is this a bug in the neo4j javascript driver/neo4j browser or are there server/client configurations I can look at to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT

[A simple example of the query pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsgkq.png). Once i can identify the A,B,C cluster and the D,E,F cluster I can interview C and D and determine if that relationship is business critical or can be disrupted. In production is seems that clusters are connected to many other clusters, making the query quickly very large.

EDIT - revised quires inline above

EDIT [Resolution] - I have built a php application that recursively performs small scope queries (graph aware driver) and composite the results in a json structure for visualization by d3. But the neo4j browser is more feature rich than my solution, so any suggestions for improvement of the query or infrastructure would be welcome.

Comment: This is probably one of the most expensive queries you could possibly run, as it will find **every single path** between **every single pair of nodes** (where a path exists) in your database, and you will also get redundant paths with the start and end nodes switched. You may be looking at millions of results (or more) depending on your database size. What are you trying to get out of this query? There's almost certainly a better and much more efficient query to get whatever you're after.

Comment: I'm trying to identify clusters of delegation relationships in an email system with a view to separating tenuously connected clusters.

Comment: As I'm not familiar with this, could you provide a high-level description of what this means, and how you would go about this with the data returned by the query? So far you've only given the pattern match query, not what you would do with this when it returns.

Comment: Here's one version of the query including a check for edge importance: 


*MATCH path = ((s:User {UserId:"indexedKey"})-[r:HasAccess*]-(t:User)) WHERE all(y IN rels(path) WHERE toInt(y.Importance) >= 3) RETURN path*
A human will analyze for clustering in the force-directed graph interface (because i haven't figured out how to do it in Cypher).

Comment: There are `hasAccess` relationships in your example, but not in your `(s)-[r:*]-(t)` query (also this will fail as-is because you have a : but no relationship type after it). You may want to add that in. Also, you're not using node labels in your query or example. If all of your nodes are of the same label, or if label doesn't matter, that's fine, but otherwise you may want to add this in too.

Comment: I was generalizing the query when i first posted. Also, mini-markdown ate the wildcard after HasAccess in my last comment.

Comment: There is an enormous difference between the generalized query and the specific query in your comments above. Not just in expected performance, but it also highly limits any advice we could give. Could you please edit your question to include your specific query instead of the generalized one (along with the included context)? You can format your code blocks with code formatting to avoid having the markdown eat parts of your query.

Comment: Also, regarding the specific query in your comment above, is this the query which is timing out, or was it a different one? Is it enough to only get nodes which satisfy the condition (reachable from :HasAccess relationship chain where all relationships of the chain have importance >= 3)? If you need relationships too, is it enough to return one possible relationship to the node? Or do you need all reachable nodes and all possible relationships to reach them all?

Comment: For this query I need all relationships except the ones within the cluster, but I don't know how to allegorically (let alone with Cypher) describe a cluster.

Comment: "All relationships except the ones within the cluster"...I'm rather confused about this. You want all relationships in the entire graph except those in the cluster? That doesn't sound right. Also, by "cluster", do you mean a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory))? APOC Procedures has [procedures for cliques](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress), including finding cliques containing a specific node.

Comment: Yes, cliques are what i'm talking about. Thanks for the vocabulary. I'm looking for nodes and edges that, when removed, will shrink the maximal clique with the goal of making the maximal clique of every user small enough to be migrate effectively. I'm running into a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when i call `CALL apoc.algo.cliques(3000) YIELD clique`. This is in a windows based neo4j instance  with `-Xss7g` set. I'm having issues getting apoc to run in my Ubuntu VM. But that'll be a separate post if I can't figure it out.